# Ajax doesn't work without alert box

Tags: javascript, ajax

the code below only works when in function setDiv, the line

```
    //alert("waarom fout");
```

is not commented, how is this possible?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <link href="stijl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <title>garage DDT</title>
    <script>
    function getHTTPObject()
    {
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else{
            alert("Your web browser does not support AJAX.");
        return null;
        }
    }


    function setDiv(s){
        //alert("waarom fout");
        if(httpObject.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById(s).innerHTML=httpObject.responseText;
        }
    }

    function vulDiv(s){
        query="occasiewagens2.php?action="+s;
        if(s=="tabel" || s=="model")
            query+="&merk="+document.getElementById("merkSelect").options[document.getElementById("merkSelect").selectedIndex].value;
        if(s=="tabel")
            query+="&model="+document.getElementById("modelSelect").options[document.getElementById("modelSelect").selectedIndex].value;
        httpObject=getHTTPObject();
        if(httpObject != null){
            httpObject.open("GET",query, true);
            httpObject.send(null);
        httpObject.onreadystatechange=setDiv(s);
    }
    }
    var httpObject=null;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div >
<?php include("header.php") ?>

    <input type="button" value="Zoek occasie" onclick="vulDiv('merk')"/>
    <p id="merk"> </p>
    <p id="model"> </p>

    <div id="tabel">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the MDN documentation which explains how to make Ajax requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning the function, you are executing it right away

```
httpObject.onreadystatechange=setDiv(s);

//vs

httpObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
    setDiv(s);
};
```